# Linux: Find a directory and creat a file in it

Tags: linux, .htaccess, directory, find

I want to make a .htaccess file in all the 'uploads' directories on the server.

I started with this:

```
find / -type d -name 'uploads'
```

and i got a long list of all directories that have a upload dir in it.

now i want to create a .htaccess file in it with this content:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|gif|png)$">
Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Can anybody help plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find can be used to execute a command in the context of every directory under a specific path.

The following command will copy a template .htaccess into every directory that matches the find criteria. You would have to create the .htaccess.template and modify the path to it in the command below:

```
find / -type d -name 'uploads' -exec cp /home/user/.htaccess.template {}/.htaccess \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, if you're using bash as your shell:

```
cat > /path/to/.htaccess <<EOF
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|gif|png)$">
Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
EOF
```

The `cat` command copies its input to its output. Its output in this case is determined by the filename following the `>`; in other words, it's the full path of the `.htaccess` file you want to write.

The `<<EOF` means that `cat` should take its input from what follows, until it encounters the string `EOF` again. That's why `EOF` appears again at the end of the input that you want copied into the file.

Once you've created this file once, you can use `find` to copy it to everywhere it's needed, using the `-exec` switch, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `find / -type d -name 'uploads'`
do
  touch $i/.htaccess
  echo "Order deny,allow\nDeny from all\n<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|gif|png)$">\nOrder Deny,Allow\n\tAllow from all\n</FilesMatch>">.htaccess

done
```

Comment: You need to be rather careful with this. It will not play nicely if any of the path names has a space in it.